# Form to Upload Images using Carrierwave

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

I've just finished creating a simple Carrierwave file upload system (via the example at http://railscasts.com/episodes/253-carrierwave-file-uploads)

Here is my model:

```
require 'carrierwave/orm/activerecord'

class Video < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :course, :qa_complete, :qa_id, :subject, :title, 
  :translate_complete, :translator_id, :type_complete, :typer_id, :video_id, :due_date, :translation_handwritten

  validates :video_id, :presence => true, :uniqueness => true #add uniqueness in db too
  mount_uploader :translation_handwritten, TranslationsUploader
end
```

Here is my form view:

```
<%= form_for @video, :html => {:multipart => true} do |f| %>
  <p>
    <%= f.file_field :translation_handwritten %>
  </p>
  <p><%= f.submit :Upload %></p>
<% end %>
```

Here is my uploader:

```
class TranslationsUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

  storage :file

  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end

  def default_url
    ActionController::Base.helpers.asset_path("fallback/" + [version_name, "default.png"].compact.join('_'))
  end

  def extension_white_list
    %w(jpg pdf png)
  end
end
```

Whenever I try actually uploading, however, it errors saying I have too many arguments:
[image]

I have tried:

1. Removing the :html => {:multipart => true} part since it is also the default. The error still comes up.
2. Replaced @video with my @user model. It didn't error! This doesn't really make any sense for what I'm trying to do. I need it to work for my video model, but why would it not error with the user model?

I'm kind of lost on where to go from here. It seems to be some sort of issue with my video model since it doesn't error with a user. Does anyone have any ideas?

Thank you!!!

Comment: Does a video belong to a user?

Comment: In this case, yes. It is through a user that this video is being accessed.

Answer (score 0):

Ok maybe try using the below in your form is video belongs to user.

```
<% form_for [@user, @video] do |f| %>
```

It might not work but you might have a nested resource which may help.